# The Rotation of an IMU is no propagated to other link in RVIZ

Tags: ros2, rviz, imu, tf2

I'm trying to make an stl file rotate into Rviz2 following the quaternion given by an IMU.
My TFtree is described as in the following picture.
I publish my data from the IMU in the same file as the th_broadcaster, an I can see my IMU move in Rviz, but my stl seems completely still.
[image: TF tftree]

urdf file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <robot name="imu_aa_3d" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <!-- ****************** ROBOT CONSTANTS *******************************  -->
  <!-- Define the size of the robot's main chassis in meters -->
  <xacro:property name="base_width" value="0.39"/>
  <xacro:property name="base_length" value="0.70"/>
  <xacro:property name="base_height" value="0.20"/>
    
  <!-- Define the shape of the robot's two back wheels in meters -->
  <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.14"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_width" value="0.06"/>

  <!-- x-axis points forward, y-axis points to left, z-axis points upwards -->
  <!-- Define the gap between the wheel and chassis along y-axis in meters -->
  <xacro:property name="wheel_ygap" value="0.035"/>

  <!-- Position the wheels along the z-axis -->
  <xacro:property name="wheel_zoff" value="0.05"/>

  <!-- Position the wheels along the x-axis -->
  <xacro:property name="wheel_xoff" value="0.221"/>

  <!-- Position the caster wheel along the x-axis -->
  <xacro:property name="caster_xoff" value="0.217"/>

  <!-- Define intertial property macros  -->
  <xacro:macro name="box_inertia" params="m w h d">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 ${pi/2}"/>
      <mass value="${m}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${(m/12) * (h*h + d*d)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" 
               iyy="${(m/12) * (w*w + d*d)}" iyz="0.0" 
               izz="${(m/12) * (w*w + h*h)}"/>
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <!-- ****************** ROBOT BASE FOOTPRINT ***************************  -->
  <!-- Define the center of the main robot chassis projected on the ground -->  
  <link name="base_footprint"/>

  <!-- The base footprint of the robot is located underneath the chassis -->
  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_footprint"/>
    <child link="base_link" />
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 ${(wheel_radius+wheel_zoff)}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <!-- ********************** ROBOT BASE *********************************  -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://imu_aa_3d/meshes/robot_base.stl" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="Red">
        <color rgba="${255/255} ${0/255} ${0/255} 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${base_length} ${base_width} ${base_height}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="40.0" w="${base_width}" d="${base_length}" h="${base_height}"/>
    
  </link>

  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>  

  <!-- *********************** IMU SETUP *********************************  -->
  <!-- Each sensor must be attached to a link.                              --> 
  <link name="IMU0"/>
  <link name="map"/>

  <joint name="imu_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="map"/>
    <child link="IMU0"/>s
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="imu_joint2" type="fixed">
    <parent link="IMU0"/>
    <child link="base_footprint"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
</robot>
```

And this is for my cpp publisher.

```
auto tf_broadcaster_ = std::make_unique<tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster>(*this);
geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped t;

t.header.stamp = this->get_clock()->now();
t.header.frame_id = "map";
t.child_frame_id = "IMU0";
t.transform.rotation.x = mesure.quat_x;
t.transform.rotation.y = mesure.quat_y;
t.transform.rotation.z = mesure.quat_z;
t.transform.rotation.w = mesure.quat_w;

t.transform.translation.x = 0.0;
t.transform.translation.y = 0.0;
t.transform.translation.z = 0.0;

tf_broadcaster_->sendTransform(t);
```